# How to give a name to a saved Image from the imagePickerController

Tags: iphone, save, uiimagepickercontroller, imagenamed

I'm using an imagePickerController to replace my existing images inside my view. The function works within the same IB-file. However I'd like to load the chosen image in another IB-File as well. I think that the solution is to give a name to the image when saved. After it is saved I'd like to call the image (by name) from my memory within my other IB-file.

Here's a snippit of code I'm using within the photopicker IB-file

```
-(IBAction)setPhoto{

    image1.image = fotoView.image;
}

-(IBAction)getCameraPicture:(id)sender
{
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsImageEditing = YES;
    picker.sourceType = (sender == takePictureButton) ? UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera :
    UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
    [self presentModalViewController: picker animated:YES];
    [picker release];
}

-(IBAction)selectExitingPicture
{
    if([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:
        UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary])
    {
        UIImagePickerController *picker= [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
        picker.delegate = self;
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
        [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
        [picker release];
    }
}

-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
      didFinishPickingImage : (UIImage *)image
                 editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo
{
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    fotoView.image = image;

    NSData* imdata =  UIImagePNGRepresentation ( image );
    UIImage* im8 = [UIImage imageWithData:imdata];
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(im8, nil, nil, nil);
}

-(void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *) picker
{
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

within my other class I'd like to call this image by means of:

```
if (#some condition){
        UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Name of the image.png"];
        [image1 setImage:img];
```

}

Help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method for image picking and saving it to the directory:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker 
        didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image
                  editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo {
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    NSString *docDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *pngFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/MyName.png",docDir];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)];
    [data writeToFile:pngFilePath atomically:YES];
}
```

Lateron you can call it by using:

```
NSString *docDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *pngFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/MyName.png",docDir];
UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:pngFilePath];
```

Comment: Great answer, also the solution I was looking for. Many Thanks